# How to Overwrite Internet Explorer Dialog's?

Tags: internet-explorer, custom-controls, embedding

I'm looking for a way to overwrite for example the dialog which pops up if you click on the "browse"-Button of a INPUT type="file" element in an HTML Page. 
I need to suppress the original dialog and show my own implementation. Is this possible in any way ?

---

The most important thing for me is to get a callback when the dialog is supposed to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution catching WM_INITDIALOG and WM_SHOWWINDOW Events for the specific dialog.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (for example, Google provides such a custom file selection dialog when uploading images to its Picasa Web Albums), but this requires using Flash. I am not aware of any Flash-free solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own control Using Flash (like RegDwight mentions) or Silverlight.

Using Silverlight you also need to create your own upload mechanism, because you will not get the full path name of the file you pointed to. I don't know how this is in Flash, but I suppose it is the same.